# The iPhone simulator in Xcode 8.2.1 runs a bit slow

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode8.2

I have noticed that when I launch the Xcode 8 iPhone simulator that actions that I make when using the simulator run incredibly slow, for example, when I maneuver to the home screen by clicking Hardware>Home or Shift+cmd+H it runs fine but when I open an application the borders make a strange animation, and when I tap a button on an application, the transitions take a long time. Sorry or such long question, but any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You might have activated debugging feature of the simulator, slow animations. 
Check debug options in simulator menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iphone simulator suddenly started running very slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348699/iphone-simulator-suddenly-started-running-very-slow)

Answer (score 5):

Try This.. Unselect the slow animations in simulator debug

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this was much appreciated. I will try it out. Thank You