# IOS 9 Simulator very laggy in comparision to IOS 11 Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, ios9

I am trying to make my current application compatible to IOS 9 devices. The very first thing I have noticed running the app for the first time on an IOS9 Simulator was that the app is running extremely slow. That means that all animations and segues are laggy although on the IOS 11 Simulator and on a real device it is running flawlessly. Unfortunately I have currently no testing device running IOS 9 on it. Additionally I can mention that the `UITableView` got a weird behavior. When scrolling through the tableview it seems that the cell are snapping in although I have set a estimated row height and there is an additional spacing after the last cell which is not existent on IOS 11.

[image: Unwanted spacing after last cell]

Strangely I have not seen any users complaining about this problem. Just questions the other way around where users are complaining about a slow IOS 11 simulator. Maybe somebody has experienced the same problem? Or am I maybe missing some settings in Xcode?

Comment: "When scrolling through the tableview it seems that the cell are snapping in although I have set a estimated row height and there is an additional spacing after the last cell which is not existent on IOS 11." Well, self-sizing cells work totally differently on iOS 9 than in iOS 11, so you would need to take that into account. You have shown no code...

Comment: "Unfortunately I have currently no testing device running IOS 9 on it" Well then, maybe this is not such a good idea. Backward compatibility is _very hard_ even under the best of circumstances; I would almost say that Apple is trying to discourage it (because new devices are how they make their money). If you cannot test on a device, perhaps the best course is not to risk it. The simulator is only a simulation and there are a lot of things it cannot do at all, plus yes, it can be laggy (the iPhone X simulator is unusable on my machine) and can draw incorrectly.

Comment: But see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348699/iphone-simulator-suddenly-started-running-very-slow?rq=1 because slow animations and segues sounds like an ordinary dumb mistake (accidentally toggling Slow Animations on).